# RBAC on Yii - Where is the association with controller methods?

Tags: yii

We have tasks, roles, and operations. 
ok.

we have associated users with certain roles.
ok.

Now we have a method called doThis() on a given controller, that we wish to assign or allow, to a certain user, or role.

Where do we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I think this is what you're looking for:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter